# If params is present not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

My url paths are this

```
/locale/country/
/locale/country/region/
```

models:

```
class Region
belongs: country
end

class Country
has_many: regions
end
```

a foreign-key country_id in regions table

This is a part of a nav partial in the layout file.

```
//block region
    - if params[:region].present? 
       %ul.thumbnails
       - @region.tags.find_each(:conditions => "active_house = true") do |a|
          %li.span2
          .thumbnail
            - a.attachments.limit(1).each do |b|
              = image_tag(b.file.url)
            .caption
              %p 
                #{link_to a.h1, tag_country_region_houses_path(@country, @region, a.name), :class => 'btn-nav', class: active_class?(tag_houses_path(a.name))} 
//block country    
    - else
        %ul.thumbnails
        - @country.tags.find_each(:conditions => "active_house = true") do |a|
           %li.span2
            .thumbnail
              - a.attachments.limit(1).each do |b|
                = image_tag(b.file.url)
             .caption
              %p 
                #{link_to a.h1, tag_country_houses_path(@country,  a.name), :class => 'btn-nav', class: active_class?(tag_houses_path(a.name))}
```

When the visitor is on the path /local/country i want show block country and when the vistor is on /locale/country/region i want to show block region.

I thought `if params[:region].present?` will do the trick. But no....how can i realize this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before the line

```
- if params[:region].present?
```

In your view, try ptinting the lines,

```
- p params[:region]
- p params[:region].present?
```

that could give you some clue about the behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
if params.has_key?(:region)
```

or if it exists but contains a nil you could test it:

```
unless params[:region].nil?
```

Comment: what is supposed to be in the `:region` parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Is it not supposed to be

```
class Region
belongs_to: country
end
```

instead of

```
class Region
belongs: country
end
```

Cheers